# Why is my CSS file not linking to my HTML file?

Tags: html, css

Here is the path I am working with - `/public_html/websystems/websystems.css`

The HTML file I am trying to link is in the `public_html` directory and named index.html

The CSS file I am trying to link is in the websystems directory and named `websystems.css`

The contents of the files are shown in the images below.

**HTML file**
[image]

**CSS file** 
[image]

Why are none of the styles I've set in my CSS file applying to my HTML file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] good question.

Comment: What happens if you use `href="websystems/websystems.css"`?

Comment: What Abhishek said is good advice. Secondly, did you try clearing the cache or hard refreshing your page? (`ctrl + F5` or `Ctrl + Shift + R`, depending on browser and OS)

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: If you upload a image of your map structure so we can see if you linked the path correctly.

Comment: Your `meta` element is broken. You never close it. Fix it: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
Also, please don't post images of your code, post your code.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this,**

```
websystems/websystems.css
```

**Note that,** (taken from [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/))

> - Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
> - Is the image in a directory **below**?
> - Is the image in a directory **above**?
>
> By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories.
>   Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a
>   look at my primitive example: [image]
>
> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts    there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep    moving forward

Comment: Very nice answer. I'd change _backwards_ to _up_ and _forward_ to _down_ in order to be consistent with your earlier terms (_below_, _above_), but maybe that's just me (and its nitpicking anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `/websystems/websystems.css` to just `websystems/websystems.css` and see if that works. That's a path relative to the current path of `index.html`.